# Rigid foam board vs Tyvek under new siding

Tags: insulation, exterior, siding, moisture

We are looking at getting new siding here in zone 5 Iowa. Our house was built in 1979 and has 2x4 walls. I have seen that if we add rigid foam insulation we need to use at a minimum of R-5. Do we need to also use something like Tyvek under or over the foam boards?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You already *almost* have an air barrier. You could simply tape the joints with appropriate tape.

From the Owens-Corning product page for their tape for their foam (no endorsement implied, just as an example of the product class existing for the application):

> HomeSealR™ Foam Joint Tape is an effective product to tape the joints
> of FOAMULAR® extruded polystyrene (XPS) board in residential vertical
> wall applications when it is used as continuous insulation over steel
> or wood wall framing. HomeSealR™ Foam Joint Tape provides reliable
> adhesion to FOAMULAR® XPS insulation. The durable backing is coated
> with an aggressive acrylic adhesive to offer excellent adhesion
> coupled with strength and is easy to handle.

Answer (score 0):

Generally yes you would put the house wrap directly over the sheathing, which means under the exterior foam insulation. The goal of the tyvek is to act as an air barrier between the outside and inside air.

Comment: Agreed, except that it might be easier (and cheaper) to tape the foam joints as noted in [Ecnerwal's answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/249144/34147). If not taping, then Tyvek would be advised

Comment: @FreeMan my concern with the taping foam approach is that the OP hasn’t made it clear what kind of foam it is. I’d it’s low perm, and acts as a vapour barrier as well, it can trap moisture in the sheathing and wall. The tyvek is vapour permeable from the inside out and would allow the sheathing to dry.

Comment: @RibaldEddie If the tyvek is sandwiched betweenthe sheathing and the foam with no air gap,how will the sheathing dry? the vapour would permiate through the sheathing, tyvek, and then the foam?

Comment: As mentioned above, there are different kinds of foam. There are plenty of rigid foam boards (unfaced, semi-permeable) that will support drying to the exterior. The tyvek is already vapour permeable because it's an air barrier, not a vapour barrier. So if the plywood/OSB sheathing gets wet, the vapour from the drying process will move through the envelope (tyvek, foam board) to the outside of the building. If the OP wanted, they could have gone with a different exterior insulation (I like rockwool panels personally). But sure, there's nothing wrong with vapour permeable foam board in so case.